# Messages appeared on boot. Do I have a virus?

Tags: security

I downloaded and ran the script located [here on pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/).

I am worried because after I updated my system and shut it down, and then started it up again, it showed a terminal session going. I don't have the terminal log because I don't know how to retrieve it...

Maybe it is normal for a system to check itself at boot time after it updates?

Does my system have a virus? Is that a safe site to use?

I have checked using ClamAV and run a rootkit scan...

Comment: virus for linux ?

Comment: I doubt you have a virus... The text on start up is normal. At the Ubuntu "loading" splash screen, tap the Esc key and see if it's the same.

Comment: edwin what do you mean esc after splash screen what should i see??

Comment: It's technically impossible (as we know it) to have a virus in Ubuntu...

Comment: @Alvar that statement needs some explanation.

Comment: @Alvar: Uhm, there's plenty of malware for Linux including Ubuntu. Any security systems with flaws can be circumvented. Show me one useful piece of software of more than 1 mio. lines of code without flaws, and I might start to believe you.

Comment: @stens97: It's normal for Linux to show some text scrolling over a terminal during boot. If the graphics adapter doesn't act up, Ubuntu just chooses to hide it behind a purple "canvas" by default. Conversely, I would find it unlikely, that a virus would show a terminal during boot just for its own sake. At which point exactly during boot did you see the terminal?

Comment: @Alvar: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24290/viri-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "check itself" you mean that during boot Ubuntu scanned your hard-dive for errors then NO, you don't have a virus, it does that normally every 36 boots or so to keep your filesystems in order...  The script itself looks ok and only helps in setting up your flash-drive...

Comment: Ok that must be what is going on ... I've booted about that many times ... Thank you.